# Xamarin [RestSharp] + [Xam.Plugin.Media] upload model containing image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I'm trying to upload an image from xamarin.forms and using restsharp for api service.

```
RestRequest uploadPostRestRequest = new RestRequest("post/create/", Method.POST);
uploadPostRestRequest.AddJsonBody(uploadPostRequest);
```

and this is my model `UploadPostRequest`

```
public class UploadPostRequest
{
    public string content;
    public byte[] image;
}
```

Question - Is it right to set image type as `byte[]`?
Would server accept this or would restsharp manage it?

If RestSharp has a nice control with this, can I just put `MediaFile` from `Xam.Plugin.Media` so I can upload it right over?

`Xam.Plugin.Media` is used for picking images from mobile device.

Too many options, so, that's why I'm looking for good advice.

Has anyone experienced this same issue before? please help.

For additional info, I cant use System.IO.File, Xamarin.Forms wont let me use it.

Comment: Restharp will not understand what a `MediaFile` is but you can get the bytes[] out of this object and use it to post it as part of the request payload.

Comment: in PCL it's not available to use System.IO.File~  like  File.ReadAll() ect. any other options for converting to byte[] or a new approach?

Answer (score 1):

When the Xam.Plugin.Media finish loading the media either from the Camera or from the Library it returns a MediaFile. This object can be converter to a byte array with something like this:

```
byte[] byteArray;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream ())
{
    mediaFile.GetStream ().CopyTo (memoryStream);
    mediaFile.Dispose ();
    byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray ();
}
```

Now you have the byte array you just need to pass it to the method that will upload the image to your backend.

Comment: well... i get this error.. <<<System.ObjectDisposedException, Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.>>>

Comment: That means you need to access it before it's disposed.. Updated the post showing the code where you get the object from the Media plugin

Comment: <<<async void PickPhotoAsync()
  {
   var mediaFile = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
   {
    PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
   });

   if (mediaFile == null)
      return;

   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
    mediaFile.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
    mediaFile.Dispose();
    fileToUploadByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
   }

  }>>>   this is my full code, and it doesnt seem to be disposed before trying to acess.. am i wrong somewhere??

Comment: Are you trying to use the mediaFile object anywhere after you convert it to byte array? If so remove the `mediaFile.Dispose ();` call.

Comment: i removed that line, still getting the exact same error.. my code is same, just removing that line.